# How do you declare and use a Set data structure in groovysh?

Tags: groovy, groovysh

I've tried:

```
groovy:000> Set<String> s = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
===> [a, b, c]
groovy:000> s
Unknown property: s
```

I want to be able to use this as a set, but even if I pass it explicitly, it turns it into an ArrayList:

```
groovy:000> joinList(["a", "b", "c", "c"])
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.joinList() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[a, b, c, c]]
Possible solutions: joinList(java.util.Set)
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This problem only occurs because you're using the Groovy Shell to test your code. I don't use the Groovy shell much, but it seems to ignore types, such that

```
Set<String> s = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
```

is equivalent to

```
def s = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
```

and the latter does of course create a `List`. If you run the same code in the Groovy console instead, you'll see that it does actually create a `Set`

```
Set<String> s = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
assert s instanceof Set
```

Other ways to create a `Set` in Groovy include

```
["a", "b", "c", "c"].toSet()
```

or

```
["a", "b", "c", "c"] as Set
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So you're recommending to use the console instead to solve this?

Comment: @smilingcow yes, I don't know why the Groovy shell ignores types like this, but I tend to use the console instead for these kinds of quick tests

Comment: groovysh ain't no REPL

Comment: Interesting. 
<code>["a", "b", "c", "c"] as Set</code> 
made my unit tests fail, but 
<code>["a", "b", "c", "c"].toSet()</code> 
is working fine. 
I'm using Spock.

Comment: Upvoted because it mentions `toSet()` - very useful.

Comment: @PatrycjaK I just fell about it too in Spock, because there's a difference: ... as Set creates a LinkedHashSet, .toSet() creates a HashSet. That broke my mocking, as in production code a KeySet was used, which is an ancestor of HashSet but not of LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 18):

**Groovy >= 2.4.0**
Setting `interpreterMode` to `true` in groovy shell by

```
:set interpreterMode true
```

should fix this issue

**Groovy < 2.4.0**
Adding a type to the variable makes it a local variable which is not available to shell's environment.

use as below in `groovysh`

```
groovy:000> s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'] as Set<String>
===> [a, b, c]
groovy:000> s
===> [a, b, c]
groovy:000> s.class
===> class java.util.LinkedHashSet
groovy:000>
```

Comment: you've omitted types in your example, so everything proceeds as expected. Any idea why the Groovy Shell seems to ignores types which leads to the kind of misunderstandings described in this question?

Comment: Adding a type to the variable makes it a local variable which is not available to shell's environment. @Dónal